# How to return BOOL when checking internet connection in XCODE

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, reachability

I want to be able to check for internet connectivity when my View loads. To predetermine the contents of my view.

I have the following viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if(![self hasInternetConnection]){
        NSLog(@"SHOW ORIGINAL DOC");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"SHOW NEW DOC");
    }
}
```

And I have a method called hasInternetConnection as follows:

```
- (BOOL)hasInternetConnection{

    NSLog(@"Starting connection test");

    internetReachableFoo = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

    // Internet is reachable
    internetReachableFoo.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach){
        // Update the UI on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"We have internet");
            return YES;
        });
    };

    // Internet is not reachable
    internetReachableFoo.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach){
        // Update the UI on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"We do not have internet");
            return NO;
        });
    };

    [internetReachableFoo startNotifier];

}
```

I don't want to use the deprecated Apple reachibility class using:

```
NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
```

How can I change the code in -(BOOL)hasInternetConnection to efficiently return a boolean for my method to work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What i do in My Projects :

Create a custom class `CheckInternet`  of type NSObject

in `CheckInternet.h` file

```
+ (BOOL) isInternetConnectionAvailable;
```

and in `CheckInternet.m` file

```
+ (BOOL) isInternetConnectionAvailable
{
Reachability *internet = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"www.google.com"];
NetworkStatus netStatus = [internet currentReachabilityStatus];
bool netConnection = false;
switch (netStatus)
{
    case NotReachable:
    {
        NSLog(@"Access Not Available");
        netConnection = false;
        break;
    }
    case ReachableViaWWAN:
    {
        netConnection = true;
        break;
    }
    case ReachableViaWiFi:
    {
        netConnection = true;
        break;
    }
}
return netConnection;
}
```

import this class to your desired class, Now you can access as

in `viewDidLoad` or any other method where you want

```
if ([CheckInternet isInternetConnectionAvailable])
{
    // internet available
}
else
{
    // no internet
 }
```

Comment: do I import CheckInternet.h to test.m or test.h?

Comment: import it in test.h or test.m it will work in both cases i guess.... you can check it :P

Comment: @Zubair It's perfect because it eliminates code repitition. First time using a global method too. I'm only in the early stages of getting used to xcode's practises and objective c :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to use Reachability code. Check here for [apple sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html). That has a lot of convenience methods to check internet availability, Wifi/WAN connectivity check etc..

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(networkChanged:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[reachability startNotifier];

- (void)networkChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{

  NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

  if(remoteHostStatus == NotReachable) { NSLog(@"not reachable");}
  else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWiFiNetwork) { NSLog(@"wifi"); }
  else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaCarrierDataNetwork) { NSLog(@"carrier"); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the Apple provided [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) class. There is a method: - (NetworkStatus)currentReachabilityStatus;

As it returns NetworkStatus. You can use this value directly or inside your function `reachabilityStatus !=  NotReachable`

Answer (score 0):

Yo can respect the asynchronicity in the implementation and modify the signature of the method to accept a block too.

First you typedef your new block in the header

```
typedef void(^ReachabilityCompletionBlock)(BOOL reachable);
```

then

```
- (void)isInternetReachable:(ReachabilityCompletionBlock)paramReachabilityBlock
{
    NSLog(@"Starting connection test");

    internetReachableFoo = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

    // Internet is reachable
    internetReachableFoo.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach){
    // Update the UI on the main thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"We have internet");
        paramReachabilityBlock(YES); 
        });
    };

    // Internet is not reachable
    internetReachableFoo.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach){
    // Update the UI on the main thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"We do not have internet");
        paramReachabilityBlock(NO);
        });
    };

    [internetReachableFoo startNotifier];
}
```