# Internet connection (Rechability) not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, reachability

I use below code for internet connection but not work(reachabilityChanged   does't call when wifi or internet change)

```
//Internet.m : 
...
@interface Internet ()
@property (nonatomic) Reachability *Wifi;
@end

@implementation Internet

-(void)checkNetwork
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
    self.Wifi = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi];
    [self.Wifi startNotifier];
}

- (void) reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification *)note
{
    Reachability* curReach = [note object];
    NSParameterAssert([curReach isKindOfClass:[Reachability class]]);
    if (curReach == self.Wifi)
    {
        NetworkStatus netStatus = [curReach currentReachabilityStatus];
        if(netStatus == NotReachable)
        {
            NSString *status=@"NO";
        }//if
        else if(netStatus == ReachableViaWiFi)
        {
            NSString *status=@"Yes";
        }//else
    }//if
}//reachabilityChanged

//ViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(callInternet) withObject:nil];
}//load

-(void)callInternet
{
    inter=[[Internet alloc]init];//inter is instance variable
    [inter checkNetwork];
}//callInternet
```

Comment: `inter` goes out of scope at the end of `viewDidLoad` and is released so it doesn't do anything. You need to keep a strong reference to it for it to work.

Comment: Please explain more.how?

Comment: Use an instance variable instead of a local variable.

Comment: All what you need you can find here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Comment: @rmaddy : it works with instance variable,thank you.but when i call it with "[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(..." not work

Comment: That sounds like a whole different issue. Either update this question with the relevant code and an explanation of what isn't working or post a new question specific to that issue.

Comment: Why are you trying to call `callInternet` on a background thread? There's no reason to do that.

Comment: then call what? i want to check internet in background to a new thread

Comment: [Check this Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28854560/how-to-return-bool-when-checking-internet-connection-in-xcode/28855098#28855098)

Answer (score 0):

@sajidZare,

in **Appdelegate.h** file

```
//Check Internet Connection
.//Define method for that
-(BOOL)checkInternetConnection;
```

in **Appdelegate.m** file

```
 //Check Internet Plugin
    #include<unistd.h>
    #include<netdb.h>

    #pragma mark Check Internet connection
    -(BOOL)checkInternetConnection {

        char *hostname;
        struct hostent *hostinfo;
        hostname = "google.com";
        hostinfo = gethostbyname (hostname);
        if (hostinfo == NULL)
        {
            NSLog(@"-> no connection!\n");
            return NO;
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"-> connection established!\n");
            return YES;
        }

    }
```

//This is best solution, try it, may be help to you.

*Another Solution*
**in your.h File**

```
    #import "Reachability.h"            // internet Rechability
    //---rechability methods---//
    @property (nonatomic) Reachability *internetReachability;
-(void)checkInternet;
```

**in your.m File**

```
-(void)checkInternet
{
    self.internetReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    if (self.internetReachability.currentReachabilityStatus==NotReachable)
    {
        NSLog(@"internet is not available..");
        [self internetAlertView];
    }


    else
        {
            NSLog(@"internet Available..");
*//Here you can do whatever you want to do//*
            [self BTN_Spark:self];
        }
        [self.internetReachability startNotifier];
    }


    -(void)internetAlertView
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!" message:@"Please check the internet connection!!!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
```

Comment: but i had given you best solution. please first try my code, if you can's satisfy then tell me. because its better than Reachability Class.

Comment: @SajjadZare, try once.

Comment: @SajjadZare, i have added another solution , this may be helpful to you.