# How to determine 4G LTE using Reachibility Call

Tags: ios, reachability, cellular-network

I have a requirement where some functionality must work different in Wifi and different in Cellular network, We used the below code to Distinguish between the network,

```
-(int)isNetworkType
{

    Reachability* reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];

    NetworkStatus netStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

    return netStatus;
}


-(void)checkCellularNetWork
{

    if ([self isNetworkType] == 2) { //via WWAN


    }
    else if(self isNetworkType] == 1){ // via WIFI

    }

}
```

Based on the NetWorkStatus we are handling the flags for the feature implementations, But 4G LTE is Supported in **WWAN** condition, How can we handle this, We need to handle the 4GLTE in cellular network only.

How can we handle this?

Comment: I recommend you [This Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28854560/how-to-return-bool-when-checking-internet-connection-in-xcode/28855098#28855098)

Comment: You can determine whether it is WIFI or WWAN. and mold it as your requirements

Comment: I am using the Similar Code in back end, But when i am connected to 4G LTE, It is not going to "ReachableViaWWAN" condition.

Comment: Then which condition is true in your case?

Comment: Sorry there is small edit it is LTE network, Actually we didnt tested in LTE as in india it is not there Yet, But according to client we are not geting alerts we placed in "ReachableViaWWAN" and it is working as like in Wifi.

Comment: so you don't have problem any more???

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use *Reachability* to detect *LTE*

This is what that helps you out

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *telephonyNetworkInfo = [CTTelephonyNetworkInfo new];
if ([telephonyNetworkInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology   isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE]) 
{
    // you are connected with LTE Connection...
}
```

don't forget to add `#import <CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>` in your `.h` file